# declaring go function throws unexpected (

Tags: go

I keep seeing build error above while running my Go code below. How can I fix this ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func do_comp(var line string) {
    for i, c := range line {
        c, ex := m[i]
            if ex == true {
                fmt.Printf("not unique character line, %c exists", c)
            }

    }
    return

}

func main() {
    st := "abracadabra"
        m := make(map[string]bool)
        do_comp(st)
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed out the error:   # command-line-arguments
  ./uniq.go:5: syntax error: unexpected var, expecting )
  Error: process exited with code 2.

Comment: That means, on line #5, the parser wasn't expecting the symbol `var`. that's not valid syntax.

Comment: `func do_comp(var line string) {` should be `func do_comp(line string) {`

Comment: Try going though the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) o get a feel for the syntax of the language. Also, _always_ format the code, which will more easily highlight simple mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import "fmt"

var m map[rune]bool

func do_comp(line string) {
    for i, c := range line {
        _, ex := m[c]
        if ex == true {
            fmt.Printf("not unique character line, %c at position %v already exists\n", c, i)
        } else {
            m[c] = true
        }

    }
    return

}

func main() {
    st := "abracadabra"
    m = make(map[rune]bool)
    do_comp(st)
}
```

Some comments:

1. If you want to use string with strictly single char you may use `rune` - it's a special type to keep exactly 1 symbol. Also go iterates strings by runes rather than strings of 1 char length, so using runes here is more convenient.
2. If you have not found a symbol first time, you may set flag in map, that you have seed that symbol. This way you will be able to find a duplicate char.
3. To make `m` accessible from all functions you may define at top level
4. Golang requires you to use all defined variables. If you have a variable which do not want to use later, use a reserved name `_` for it.

You may try it on https://play.golang.org/p/u9g6VxjCHH